# Direct evaluation of fp expression

Tags: calculations, fp

This code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}
\begin{document}
\FPeval{result}{clip(cos(pi))}
$\cos(\pi)=$\result
\end{document}
```

would produce the following output:

[image]

Is it possible to use the result of fp expressions directly without the necessity to have them pre-computed and stored in a permanent variable so that I could transform the code to the following form:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}
\begin{document}
$\cos(\pi)=$<fp expression>
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not sure if this approach has any gotcha's.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}
\newcommand\FPuse[1]{\FPeval{\result}{#1}{\result}}
\begin{document}
$\cos(\pi)=\FPuse{clip(cos(pi))}$\

$\sin(\pi/3)=\FPuse{sin(pi/3)}$

$\sin(\pi/3)=\FPuse{round(sin(pi/3),3)}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

In the comments below, jfbu and I discuss why I grouped `{\result}` at the end of the `\FPuse` definition.  First, let's see what happens if I ungroup it:

```
\newcommand\FPuse[1]{\FPeval{\result}{#1}\result}
```

The result on the first operation is

[image]

What we see is that `\result` sets itself as `{} - 1`, using a binary minus sign.  The conclusion is that `\FPeval{}{}` creates a `\bgroup...\egroup` quantity that, in math mode, causes the subsequent minus sign to act in a binary fashion.  Thus, the only way to eliminate this problem (without changing the `fp` package), is to isolate the final `\result` in its own group, as I did in my original code.

While jfbu has probed a bit into the guts of `fp`, I am no expert to know if the `fp` code can be revised to use `\begingroup...\endgroup` instead (which is truly transparent in math mode) or not.  I do know that `fp` has a few issues, for example, a stray space is introduced via `\FPpow` which has to be `\unskip`ed after its use.

See jfbu's comments below for more information on the group issue.

Comment: the 18th decimal is not correctly rounded by fp, it should be a 7. But I don't recall what fp's doc (which iirc is very short) says about this. edit: I went a bit fast because there is first Pi then division by 3, then sine. Thus asking for correctly rounded final result is a bit harsh.

Comment: @jfbu "Quibbles and bits"?

Comment: nono ;-) just comparing: Maple is even worse it gives `...649` for `evalf(sin(Pi/3.));` with `Digits:=18;`, one needs `Digits:=19;` to see correctly what is the 18th decimal...

Comment: in fact it is in nature of things if precision of intermediate computations is not big enough.

Comment: @jfbu I am reminded of joke about a job interview with 3 applicants, in which the final question is, "what does 1+1 equal".  The punchline of which is, the mathematician, with a full blackboard of proofs proclaims "2", the engineer, with a blazing calculator, proclaims "2.0000 +/- .0001", and the lawyer thinks hard for a minute, before asking, "what would you like it to equal?"

Comment: +1 and hard to tell for sure who is closest to truth: even the mathematician could have said "0 in characteristic two"...

Comment: about serious things ;-): in your post you use braces around `\result`. I would see the point of (sorry hit wrong key on keyboard too early) `\newcommand\FPuse[1]{{\FPeval{\result}{#1}\result}}` but not of `{\result}`.

Comment: @jfbu Try them both and observe the difference.  Hint: think unary versus binary.

Comment: surprising. This looks like an issue with fp. Notice that `$\sin(\pi/3)= {\def\foo{x}\edef\bar{\foo} -1}$` has no problem whatsoever. I must do `$\sin(\pi/3)= {\def\foo{x}\edef\bar{\foo} {}-1}$` to create similar issue. The braces look to me as a work-around to an after effect of use of `\FPeval`. This sounds like a problem with `\FPeval`. I have not tried to debug it.

Comment: The main routine `\FP@@upn` in `fp-upn.sty` uses `\bgroup` and `\egroup` rather than `\begingroup` and `\endgroup`. But there are also many locations where the code does  `{...\global\def...}` and this by itself is enough to trigger the issue. Ah.. non expandable code ... Perhaps you could add a word of explanation why you use  `{\result}` ?

Answer (score 6):

Not with `fp`. It is possible with `expl3`, though.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn
% make an internal function available to the user
\cs_set_eq:NN \fpeval \fp_eval:n
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

$\cos(\pi)=\fpeval{cos(pi)}$

$\sin(\pi/3)=\fpeval{sin(pi/3)}$

$\sin(\pi/3)=\fpeval{round(sin(pi/3),3)}$

\end{document}
```

[image]